# Why does adding `sm-4` make adding a margin to embedded videos too wide?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

So, just to make a test I've made this

```
<div id="reo" class="reo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m-3 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col m-3 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col m-3 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it works as expected, but if I add some column sizes, like `col-sm-4` to each column, my videos are too big to be in a row, and they stack.

Although the code is pretty fine as it is, I'm wondering why giving a specific size to the column messes up the embedded videos responsive behavior, when it doesn't appear to with anything else I've put into a col.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have in your class list the class name: m-3 which gives margin of 1rem for each of the divs, and this will cause that the width of any col-sm-4 (33.333333%) to be added to it (1rem) and this will make the three divs width more than 100% with (3rem).

Try removing this class and use padding instead (p-3) somehow.